# perl regex \Q mac os x

Tags: regex, macos, perl

I'm trying to do a text search&replace using perl in the os x terminal.  I'm trying to replace a string of special characters "!@#$%^&*()" with the string 'special characters', using this line:

```
perl -p -e 's/\Q!@#$%^&*()\E/special characters/g' 'hello.txt' > 'hello_new.txt'
```

But it's not working. Does the \Q not work on OS X? It's supposed to disable regex pattern matching. I don't want to have to escape the characters myself.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`$%` a special variable in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and is being interpolated.

You can confirm this by simply outputting your LHS as a string:

```
$ perl -MData::Dump -E 'dd "\Q!@#$%^&*()\E"'
"\\!\\\@\\#0\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)"
```

To fix you just need to escape the `$` in the LHS of your regex:

```
perl -pe 's/\Q!@#\$%^&*()\E/special characters/g' 'hello.txt' > 'hello_new.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

[perldoc perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) notes that

> `\Q` Disable pattern metacharacters until `\E`

but it appears that `$` is not sufficient of a pattern metacharacter; it is an everything else metacharacter introducing variable references, and most of the special characters combine with `$` to make a special variable per [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).  So, you will need to escape `$` anyway if you write it verbatim into a regex, even within `\Q…\E`.

Or you can use variations on this theme:

```
$ echo '!@#$%^&*()' |
> perl -l -e '$rx = q{!@#$%^&*()}; $qx = qr/\Q$rx\E/; print $qx;
>             while (<>) { s/$qx/special characters/; print; }'
(?^:\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\))
special characters
$
```

The first line of output is the regex, where you can see that all the characters, including `$`, are escaped with backslashes.  The second line shows that when the
input is the string of characters, the pattern is recognized and replaced.

Tested with home-built Perl 5.22.0 and system-provided Perl 5.18.2 on Mac OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan — with the same output on both.  And (home-built) Perl 5.8.9 gives a slightly different output for the printable regex:

```
(?-xism:\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\))
```

Note that adapting this to your original regex yields:

```
$ perl -l -e '$qx = qr/\Q!@#$%^&*()\E/; print $qx'
(?^:\!\@\#0\^\&\*\(\))
$
```

The `$` and `%` are replaced by `0`.  That's because `$%` is also known as `$PAGE_FORMAT_NUMBER`:

> `$%`
>   The current page number of the currently selected output channel.
>   Mnemonic: % is page number in nroff.